Disable lightning pill tooltip
i have a lightning pill and when i hover over it, it displays the same label as tooltip. i want to disable the tooltip such that the click and remove events work.
how can i remove just the default on hover tooltip.
<lightning-pill label="My Pill" onclick={click} class="my-pill"></lightning-pill>

i tried pointer-events: none; but it disabled even the on click event
